# Because SDL Web could not connect to the notification system, it cannot receive push notifications

Tags: web8.5

Today SDL Web8.5 installed in new server. I try open CME url first time and got this error  **"Because SDL Web could not connect to the notification system, it cannot receive push notifications."**. Let me know any configuration missing....

[image]

When I open CME got this error:
 `One or more errors occurred.`Unexpected`character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. Component: NotificationHub Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.b__1(String raw) at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41(Task`1 t) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Sdl.SignalR.SignalRMessageBus.SignalRMessageBus.Initialize() at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args) at Sdl.SignalR.Backplane.Common.HubLoader.CreateMessageBus(String assembly, String scaleoutConfigurationType, String scaleoutMessageBusType, Boolean patchOnReceived, Object[] backplaneConfigurationParameters) at Sdl.SignalR.Backplane.Common.HubLoader.Load(IAppBuilder app, String assembly, String scaleoutConfigurationType, String scaleoutMessageBusType, String hubAssemblyName, Boolean patchOnReceived, Object[] backplaneConfigurationParameters) at Tridion.Web.NotificationHub.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`

Looking recommendation and solution for this issue.

Comment: My guess is that you have a firewall policy that is blocking the port on the which the notifications are communicated.

Comment: it`s working fine in three development server and one SIT server. I check tomorrow morning once second again!!!

Comment: When I open CME got this error:

Comment: you should mention this is a server with Site Minder protection and none of the other servers have it :)

Comment: It's indeed possible that Site Minder is interfering and returning a different response. You should be able to see that using a network monitoring tool such as Wireshark.

Comment: @Sudhakar - Did you ever solve this, I am having a similar issue when I enable our SSO modules for the CME

Comment: Issue resolved and working perfectly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs SSO enabled CME, To resolve by adjusting the following config values.

**[Install Path]SDL Web\hubs\backplaneHub\Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <tridionConfigSections>
    <sections>
      <clear />
      <add filePath="..\..\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config" />
    </sections>
  </tridionConfigSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="OpenAmModule64" />
        <remove name="SsoAgentHttpModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager
          checkCertificateName="false"
          checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** 
Also, ensure this below URL response is getting 200 response code with javascript output, may be this URL throw 500 error due to SSO enabled.

https://CMS-URL/hubs/notificationHub/signalR/hubs

Comment: I was facing the same issue in Tridion Sites 9.0 I have made the above changes [Install Path]SDL Web\hubs\NotificationHub\Web.config that resolve the issue, in your answer path is [Install Path]SDL Web\hubs\backplaneHub\Web.config and I have refered this link as well https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004585here alos they mentioned SSO need to be disabled in the notification hub.